# merge multi same html elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

I like to move the text only in div make it like:

```
 <div class="field-item even">
 Job1<p><a href="">Name1</a></p>
 </div>
```

etc...

and i like it to be merge and remove all the .field-name-field-brief-text-team div

any help please...
Thanks

```
 <div class="field field-name-field-team field-type-entityreference">
   <label>Team</label>
   <div class="field-items">

     <div class="field-item even">
     <p><a href="">Name1</a></p>
     </div>

    <div class="field-item odd">
    <p><a href="">Name2</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="field-item even">
      <p><a href="">Name3</a></p>
    </div>

   </div>
 </div>

<div class="field field-name-field-brief-text-team field-type-text">
    <div class="field-items">

    <div class="field-item even">Job1</div>
    <div class="field-item odd">Job2</div>
    <div class="field-item even">Job3</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to merge the second `div` into the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this achieves your requirements:

```
$('.field-name-field-brief-text-team .field-item').each(function (i) {
    var to = $('.field-item').eq(i)[0],
        toFirst = to.getElementsByTagName('*')[0],
        from = this,
        txt = document.createTextNode(this.textContent);
    to.insertBefore(txt,toFirst);
}).remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w4xXv/).

And a slightly-altered version of the above, using an alternate way of retrieving the DOM node from the jQuery selector (using `get(0)`) and for finding the first child element of the `to` node (`to.firstChild`). These are merely alternatives, and not necessarily recommended over the previous approach:

```
$('.field-name-field-brief-text-team .field-item').each(function (i) {
    var to = $('.field-item').eq(i).get(0),
        toFirst = to.firstChild,
        from = this,
        txt = document.createTextNode(this.textContent);
    to.insertBefore(txt,toFirst);
}).remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w4xXv/1/).

Edited to offer the fastest (per [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/moving-text-around-with-jquery-or-dom)) approach:

```
$('.field-name-field-brief-text-team .field-item').each(function (i) {
    var to = $('.field-item')[i]
        toFirst = to.firstChild,
        txt = document.createTextNode(this.textContent);
    to.insertBefore(txt,toFirst);
}).remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w4xXv/2/).

---

**Edited** to add the requested (in comments, below) `:` to the text:

```
$('.field-name-field-brief-text-team .field-item').each(function (i) {
    var to = $('.field-item')[i]
    toFirst = to.firstChild,
        txt = document.createTextNode(this.textContent + ': ');
    to.insertBefore(txt, toFirst);
}).remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w4xXv/3/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
- Plain JavaScript:

  - [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode).
  - [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.firstChild).
  - [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.getElementsByTagName).
  - [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

Comment: Thank you so much David ;) .. very nice

Comment: Updated the answer to add a `:` after the text.

Comment: Thank you so much again :) your amazing .. can i add u to my facebook

Comment: If you really want to, then yes. Though I do maintain a separation of my Facebook from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    target = $("div.field-name-field-team").find("div.field-item");
    source = $("div.field-name-field-brief-text-team").find("div.field-item");

    for(var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        $(target[i]).html($(source[i]).html() + $(target[i]).html());
    }
});
```

Output:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-team field-type-entityreference">
   <label>Team</label>
   <div class="field-items">

     <div class="field-item even">Job1
     <p><a href="">Name1</a></p>
     </div>

    <div class="field-item odd">Job2
    <p><a href="">Name2</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="field-item even">Job3
      <p><a href="">Name3</a></p>
    </div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

To remove all `.field-name-field-brief-text-team div`, use

```
$("div.field-name-field-brief-text-team").remove()
```